# Select last week when a new year splits the week

Tags: mysql

Today is Jan 11. Last week, in my needs, is the week from December 29th to January 4th. The year of 2019 ended on a tuesday, and 2020 started on a wednesday.

My program has been giving me all kinds of problems with this, as I used yearweek() to add and subtract weeks for reports.

I don't know how to make a query which is "new-years" proof. The week in number from 1 to 52 or whatever isn't going to work. I just need to calculate whatever period occurred from LAST Sunday to a week ago (last saturday)

My yearweek thing will work almost all year, and I could make custom queries for the end or beginning of the year, but I'd rather have something that works every single time. Previous searches haven't come up with anything that is "new-years" proof.

`WHERE YEARWEEK(appointment.start) = YEARWEEK(NOW(0),0)-1`

isn't working today. And the same math with +1 wasn't working at the end of 2019

here's the exact query:

```
SELECT Appointment.start, Appointment.jobID, Appointment.inter_id, Appointment.subject, Appointment.location,
Appointment.outcome_id, Appointment.region, Appointment.language, Interpreters.First_Name, Interpreters.Last_Name
FROM Appointment
left join  Interpreters on Appointment.inter_id = Interpreters.inter_id
WHERE YEARWEEK(start) = YEARWEEK(NOW(0),0)-1
```

Comment: Please show table schema or at least mention the exact datatype for the column :)

Comment: added the whole query, thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Ignore any irrelevant columns which, in this instance, would appear to be almost all of them.

Comment: Strawberry your input is well taken. I'll make minimum reproducible code in any future question I ask (the first time - I did add it later here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out so I'm posting this for anyone who may need it.

I realized that none of the week functions in mysql are going to work for my needs, so I need to calculate weeks based on intervals from the current day of the week. So to make these work, I had to make extensive use of the dayofweek() function. It's long and I wish I could make it shorter but I didn't see any other way, if I wanted to do all the functionality in sql and NOT in php or any other front end language. I think there are probably others who have the same needs as I do, so it would be nice if some future version of mysql includes some functions that can do this stuff built-in.

The math to subtract so I could get last week and this week had a peculiar effect if the day was sunday, because rather than returning 1-1=0, it was returning 7. Obviously, they programmed it like that for a reason, 1-7 are the only values that can take. So to overcome that I had to use the cast() function to convert the dayofweek of the current date to an integer.

This gets me this Sunday:
`select date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate() -1)) day)`

And so this gets me last Sunday
`select (date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate() -1)) day), interval 7 day))`

and finally to get last saturday
`select (date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate() -1)) day), interval 1 day))`

So I have to use some greater or less than or equal to operators. Here's the final code.

```
select Appointment.start, Appointment.subject from Appointment
where date(Appointment.start)
>=
 (date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate() -1)) day), interval 7 day))
AND date(Appointment.start)
<=
 (date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval (dayofweek(curdate() -1)) day), interval 1 day))  
ORDER BY `Appointment`.`start` DESC
```

I saved these as views, so for anyone who wants to use the code and finds this on google, here's the full code of each view, which I confirmed works by manually setting different dates on my system.

View name: last_week_billable_jobs

```
select `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` AS `start`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`jobID` AS `jobID`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` AS `inter_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`subject` AS `subject`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`location` AS `location`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_confirmed` AS `is_confirmed`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_authorized` AS `is_authorized`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` AS `outcome_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`region` AS `region`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`language` AS `language`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`First_Name` AS `First_Name`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`Last_Name` AS `Last_Name` from (`Calendar`.`Appointment` left join `Calendar`.`Interpreters` on((`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` = `Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`inter_id`))) where ((cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) >= (curdate() - interval (cast(dayofweek(curdate()) as signed) + 6) day)) and (cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) <= (curdate() - interval (cast(dayofweek(curdate()) as signed) + 0) day)) and (`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` < 8)) order by `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start`
```

view name: this_week_billable_jobs:

```
select `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` AS `start`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`jobID` AS `jobID`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` AS `inter_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`subject` AS `subject`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`location` AS `location`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` AS `outcome_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_confirmed` AS `is_confirmed`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_authorized` AS `is_authorized`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`region` AS `region`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`language` AS `language`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`First_Name` AS `First_Name`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`Last_Name` AS `Last_Name` from (`Calendar`.`Appointment` left join `Calendar`.`Interpreters` on((`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` = `Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`inter_id`))) where ((cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) >= (curdate() - interval (cast(dayofweek(curdate()) as signed) - 1) day)) and (cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) <= (curdate() - interval (cast(dayofweek(curdate()) as signed) - 7) day)) and (`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` < 8)) order by `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start`
```

view name: next_week_billable_jobs:

```
select `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` AS `start`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`jobID` AS `jobID`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` AS `inter_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`subject` AS `subject`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`location` AS `location`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` AS `outcome_id`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`region` AS `region`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_confirmed` AS `is_confirmed`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`is_authorized` AS `is_authorized`,`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`language` AS `language`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`First_Name` AS `First_Name`,`Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`Last_Name` AS `Last_Name` from (`Calendar`.`Appointment` left join `Calendar`.`Interpreters` on((`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`inter_id` = `Calendar`.`Interpreters`.`inter_id`))) where ((cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) >= (curdate() + interval (8 - dayofweek(curdate())) day)) and (cast(`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start` as date) <= (curdate() + interval (14 - dayofweek(curdate())) day)) and (`Calendar`.`Appointment`.`outcome_id` < 8)) order by `Calendar`.`Appointment`.`start`
```

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out your starting and ending dates is a preparatory step, not a part of your query. You didn't mention what programming language so pardon some guessing: PHP has [a feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert "last sunday" into a numeric date (and then another one to reformat PHP's date into a date MySQL will like). Node.js and other languages either have similar features built in, or installable -- for example, the node ecosystem has a [module called `moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment), and a few others competing to supplant it.

So in a nutshell, you:

1. Get whatever source information you have, for the starting and ending dates you need
2. Then convert those two dates into strings formatted the way MySQL likes it, which (in most projects) is `YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59`. ([documentation for MySQL date, datetime, and timestamp types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html))
3. And you `select` the data you need `where` the date field is `>=` (greater than or equal to) your starting date, and `<=` (less than or equal to) your ending date. ([Documentation for MySQL Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html))

Comment: The front end is in php, but the query is all mysql - It's saved as a "view" so it can be used by multiple programs. I think what I need is something involving dayofweek